# Problema en ruta al intentar borrar archivo con UNLIKN en php

Tags: php, laravel

Hola gente tengo el siguiente problema, necesito borrar un archivo con php, estoy utilizando el comando unlink hasta aquí todo bien , el problema lo tengo a la hora de montar la url con el nombre del archivo como variable, e intentado varios pero sin resultado alguno. La url de mi variable $image_path empieza con public_patch() ya que uso el framework de laravel y la carpeta de imagenes esta dentro de la ruta que me facilita public_path la ruta public se lee correctamente lo que me falla es la variable

**Intento 1** url devuelta -> ERROR: unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\reserva_barcos\public\imagenes\barcos{PRINCIPAL-5fa2c76c0abf0azul-mar-naturaleza-oceano-wallpaper-preview.jpg})

```
    $imagen_principal = "PRINCIPAL-5fa2c76c0abf0azul-mar-naturaleza-oceano-wallpaper-preview.jpg";

    $image_path = public_path()."\imagenes\barcos\{$imagen_principal}";
   
    unlink($image_path);
```

**Intento 2** url devuelta -> ERROR: unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\reserva_barcos\public\imagenes\barcos'PRINCIPAL-5fa2c76c0abf0azul-mar-naturaleza-oceano-wallpaper-preview.jpg')

```
    $imagen_principal = "PRINCIPAL-5fa2c76c0abf0azul-mar-naturaleza-oceano-wallpaper-preview.jpg";

    $image_path = public_path()."\imagenes\barcos\'$imagen_principal'";
   
    unlink($image_path);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la diagonal invertida es un caracter de escape y, por tanto, también debe escaparse para poder usarla en una cadena delimitada por comillas dobles: `"\\"`

Prueba con:

```
$imagen_principal = "PRINCIPAL-5fa2c76c0abf0azul-mar-naturaleza-oceano-wallpaper-preview.jpg";
$image_path = public_path()."\\imagenes\\barcos\\{$imagen_principal}";
unlink($image_path);
```

**Importante:** En Windows no deberías tener problemas con esto, pero, en ambientes LINUX debes usar `/` o, en todo caso, la constante [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dir.constants.php) para evitar cualquier problema.

Comment: Brutal amigo muchisimas gracias, que cosa mas tonta pero mas inesperada jajajaja